# bash while [: too many arguments

Tags: bash, while-loop

```
#!/bin/bash

number=0
while [ $number -lt 10 ];do
echo "$number"
number='expr $number + 1'
done
echo 'script complete!'
```

=> this results in

```
0
./while.sh: line 4: [: too many arguments
script complete!
```

I've tried ...

```
while [ $number -lt 10 ]
```

to

```
while [ '$number' -lt 10 ]
```

and

```
while [[ $number -lt 10 ]]
```

which doesn't work at all..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using wrong quotes for expression evaluation; single quote(`'`) instead of backquote(`` ` ``). Try this..

```
number=`expr $number + 1`
```

Comment: Two points about the original: in general you should use `number=$(expr $number + 1)` in place of backquotes, and you should use `number=$(( number + 1))` in place of `expr`.

Comment: Or, even better, ((number++)). Option added to answer. :)